# Ace editor Detect if Change happen via Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, onchange, detect, ace-editor

```
editor.getSession().on("change",function(editing){
    if (ide.curOp && ide.curOp.command.name){
        console.log("change when pressing keys");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Changed when Click on autocomplete list or programically.");
        // This change is programmatically but if its via click on autocomplete list or not? 
        // If its via click on autocomplete I want to save document else want to ignore.
    }
});
```

My comment in code is explaining my question well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer largely depends on what you call "programical", anything editor does is done via api calls so everything is "programical". E.g. if someone adds a `<button onclick='editor.setValue("")'>` will change caused by it be "programical" or not.

If you want to distinguish api calls made by your code from others, use a boolean variable and set it to true before calling into ace api, and to false after that.

```
var ignoreChanges = false
editor.session.on("change", function(delta){
    if (ignoreChanges) return console.log("ignore changes made by me")
    console.log("handle changes made in some other way")    
})
function applyChange() {
    try {
        ignoreChanges = true
        // call some editor api here
        editor.insert("...")
    } finally {
        ignoreChanges = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I just changed comments in code above, programmatically means change via api. my issue is I want to save document if user made changes else don't save. Now when I click from autocomplete list, it goes to else case whereas I need it in user made changes case. hope I explained well

Comment: yes very right , smart man.:). do we have a solution. Now you may also understand my other question to disable undomanager aswell so not to conflict b/w undomanager of different collaborators. These two last question will complete stage one of my editor, I will be very thankful if you could help please.

Comment: Unfortunately that is quite involved to implement. Take a look at existing solutions like sharejs, firebase or c9.ide.collab. The last one uses ignoreChanges flag for ignoring changes made by itself https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.collab/blob/master/ot/document.js#L192
and uses modified version of undomanger to rebase undo stack https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.collab/blob/master/ot/document.js#L737, you can also use your change transformation algorithm for that

Comment: that ignoreChanges flag idea works, that was simple but really nice. Thanks. I am one step away to complete my realtime editor now. I will be really thankful if you could please keep discussing undomanager issue on another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967399/ace-editor-pause-disable-undomanager