# Ace Editor Pause/Disable UndoManager

Tags: stack, ace-editor, undo-redo, disabled-input, pause

- Is there any way to remove specific stack value from UndoManager

**OR**

- any function to `pause/disable` and `start/enable` UndoManager again.

I want **not to push** specific data to `UndoManager's stack`.

Comment: it is not possible to not push deltas to the stack, since in that case undoing previous deltas won't be possible, you need to also transform the deltas

Comment: a user said " Unfortunately that is quite involved to implement. Take a look at existing solutions like sharejs, firebase or c9.ide.collab. The last one uses ignoreChanges flag for ignoring changes made by itself github.com/c9/c9.ide.collab/blob/master/ot/document.js#L192 and uses modified version of undomanger to rebase undo stack github.com/c9/c9.ide.collab/blob/master/ot/document.js#L737, you can also use your change transformation algorithm for that – a user 2 hours ago "

Comment: c9.ide.collab I guess this code var rev = session.$undoManager.startNewGroup();
                    session.$undoManager.markIgnored(rev); but I suppose your api don't have markIgnore and startNewGroup() function, right? Could you please explain a little more so I can proceed. I even don't understand the hint.

Comment: looks like c9.ide.collab uses not fully implemented experimental version of the required api https://github.com/c9/core/blob/master/node_modules/ace/lib/ace/undomanager.js#L84

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to simply not push deltas to the stack, since in that case undoing previous deltas won't be possible, you need to also transform the deltas around skipped delta.
Say if you have a document `"xyz"` to which `{insert, 2, "a"}` is applied to obtain `"xyaz"` and then `{insert, 1, "b"}` to get `"xbyaz"`. Now to undo the first edit but keep second one you need to apply `{delete, 2+1, "a"}`. The algorithm for doing this is not very complex, but it requires to handle many branches, so can get hairy. Ace doesn't provide an api for this atm.